# Search query function on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an album that has images. I'm having a problem with doing the search function. I want to search for photos with the following caption. Here's what I did so far.

Albums table:

```
| id | album_name | sort |
|----|------------|------|
| 1  | album_1    | 3    |
| 2  | album_2    | 2    |
| 3  | album_3    | 1    |
```

Photos table:

```
| id | album_id | name  | sort |
|----|----------|-------|------|
| 1  | 1        | name1 | 1    |
| 2  | 1        | name2 | 2    |
| 3  | 2        | name3 | 3    |
```

and the following relations on my models:

Photo.php

```php
public function album()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Album::class);
}
```

Album.php

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class, 'album_id', 'id)->orderBy('sort');
}
```

GalleryController.php

```
public function index(Request $request)
{    
    $photos =  Album::has('images')->orderBy('sort')->with('images')->get();
}
    
if (!empty($request->search)) {
    $photos = Album::whereHas('images', function($query) use ($request) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
    })->with('images')->get();
```

The search function works but if I search for a specific image within the album it returns all of the images in that album.

Comment: For specific data you need to delete the `like` from query `where('name, $request->search);` it will give you the expected result

Comment: `'name,` is missing a closing quote `'`. As is `'%);`. Better to copy/paste your code instead of typing it here

Comment: Hello, @Espresso sorry for not explaining it properly. The search function works. Let's just say that I have the following names in an album. "John" , "jane", etc. If I search for John the one that's being retrieve is the whole album. Where as I only need the photo with the name "John". Thanks for the help.

Comment: @brombeer agreed. I was using my phone to do this. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: why you are querying Album and not photos tables

Comment: `whereHas` is working as expected. What it is doing is returning all albums that have an image that matches the search query; it then returns all that albums images too.

Comment: Hello @flakerimi I have a function that also do album sorting. If for example I have 3 albums (eg: album 1, album 2, album 3) if I move album 3 in front it also needs to be reflected on the page. I hope you get the idea, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very pretty, but this is basically what you want.
I've commented the code to explain it.

```php
if (!empty($request->search)) {
    $queryString = '%' . $request->search . '%';
    $queryClosure = function ($query) use ($queryString) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', $queryString);
    };

    // Get only albums that have images that match the query string.
    // This will filter the albums, not the images.
    $photos = Album::whereHas('images', $queryClosure)
    // Now filter the images of those albums.
    ->with(['images' => $queryClosure])
    // Return the collection.
    ->get();
}
```

Edit:
I have updated the answer to use [Tim Lewis's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis) suggestion from the comments.
Since the closure is repeated for both steps, we can store it in a variable to keep the code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Even cleaner is to define `$closure = function($query) use ($queryString) { ... }`, then do `Album::whereHas('images', $closure)->with(['images' => $closure])`  Unless the closure has different functionality, you don't need to type it twice.

Comment: @TimLewis Good idea, I've updated the answer with this suggestion!

Comment: Hello @JustCarty Thank you for answering. I tried your answer and it's working perfectly. I just tweaked a few on my end. Thanks for the help! Cheers!

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion @TimLewis